# When is the official release date of Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11, windows-11-upgrade

When is the official release date of Windows 11? And will Win 10 genuine users will be eligible for a free upgrade?

Comment: Have you tried to google these questions? [This](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-11) would probably be in the top results. It has an answer to both of your questions.

Comment: Microsoft has only indicated later this year and sometime in 2022.  As with any release it will be a rolled out to compatible devices slowly.  As Microsoft as indicated on their blog this question does not seem well researched

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft currently hints at somewhere later this year on their [Windows 11 page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-11):

> Windows 11 isn’t here yet, but will be coming later this year.

..as well as the holiday season on the [official Windows forums](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-11-faq/8d24706c-3bb9-4a6e-91a0-e9ea7be02fc5):

> **I want to upgrade to Windows 11. How is it available?**
>
> Windows 11 would be available later this holiday season for general
> public. It is available for testing in the Windows Insider Program
> next week.

Since there is no official hard date yet, this is currently the best available data to go on.

Upgrading to Windows 11 will be [free of charge](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-11-faq/8d24706c-3bb9-4a6e-91a0-e9ea7be02fc5) for current owners of Windows 7, 8 and 10 licenses:

> **Do I have to pay for Windows 11?**
>
> If you do not have an existing license of Windows 7,8 or 10, you would
> need to buy a copy when Windows 11 becomes available. If you have an
> existing license of Windows, the upgrade is free of charge.

Comment: I think it's funny that MS is including free upgrades from Win 7 and Win 8, given that they are also requiring a processor built in the last few years... long after either of those operating systems were sold.  Of course, it does indicate that an old license that isn't tied to any hardware will still be good, so that's something.